# Get mid point on face of Object3D

Tags: javascript, three.js

What is the best way to detect a mid point on face of an Object3D, so I can access it anytime and point camera to it? I am wondering to create a Points object as a child of my Object3D, but I struggle on creating it with this piece of code:

```
let dotGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
dotGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
let dotMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( {size: 1, sizeAttenuation: false} );
console.log(dotGeometry);
console.log(dotMaterial);
this.dot = new THREE.Points(dotGeometry, dotMaterial);
this.cue.add(this.dot);
```

I am getting an error this case:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to
> object

Comment: What is `this.cue`?

Comment: You only want to center the camera on the object or on an specific point of the object? If you want the first one you can simply use the [`camera.lookAt()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Object3D.lookAt) function. There is no need to calculate and store a midpoint. The second one would require [raycasting](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster) and the `lookAt`. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: @Marquizzo it.s a box objects. I want to point my camera on the face of it.

Comment: @adelriosantiago I need to center my camera on the specific face of my object, so I guess the second option. It wold be great to look on an example. 
At the moment I added a small box as a child of my parent box and center camera on it. If there is a better solution please tell.